# Naming in Go for proper nouns that begin with a lower case letter

Tags: go

How do you name a type if it should be public/exported and the name should stand for: iPhoneX, iOS, eBay, etc.

Do you name them IPhoneX and IOS? or how do you name a type if the name in real world starts with lowercase letter?

Comment: There is no possible way to answer this, except to repeat the rules that exported variables must begin with a capital letter.  Beyond that, it's an opinion-based question.

Comment: You could ask: How to _not_ export nouns like "Amazon","Google" or "Facebook". This is obviously a non-problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start the name with uppercase letter if you want to have it exported anyway, so I would say that your proposed names would be fine for cases in which you need such names.